# How do I move the pivot point of an object?

Tags: object-mode

I know there are other questions and answers that cover how to set the origin to the center or to the 3D cursor, but let's say I have the pivot point almost where I want it and I just want to move it a little forward or back.

I can do it by creating a new object moving it to the position, setting the cursor to the object position then setting the origin to the cursor position then deleting that object, but that is really convoluted there must be a better way right?

Comment: Looks like this is available in 2.81: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCxnrwbsdlw&feature=youtu.be&t=193

Answer (score 9):

For people who don't want to watch a 5-minute YouTube video for a question that should take five seconds to answer:

- Go to the Options dropdown in the upper right
- Select the "Origin" checkbox
- Use the move tool to move the crosshair that appears at the pivot

Answer (score 1):

Just enter **Edit mode** and move the object.

You can use the Top, Front, and Left views to align it better.
See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Are you moving the pivot to the object, or the object to the pivot?

Comment: I'm moving the object.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not a way to move the pivot point like you want in Blender 2.8. It will be a feature in Blender 2.81 though. I usually use Shift+S (cursor to selected) to snap the cursor to multiple or one vertex, edge or face and then snap pivot point to cursor.

If you want the pivot point outside the object you can always move the cursor to that place and snap pivot point. You don't need a new object now the cursor exist in 3D-space.

Never the less, ability to move pivot point without help of the cursor is much welcome.

Edit:
Now blender 2.81 is here and you can control the pivot point separately. Here's how. [How to move pivot point separately in blender 2.81](https://youtube.com/watch?v=-CiWNcPB1CY)

Comment: Now blender 2.81 is here and you can control the pivot point separatley. Here's how. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CiWNcPB1CY

Comment: Finally, this is such an overdue feature Haiku please post this as the answer so it can be up-voted and come up as google's result.